# Targeting specific carriers in Android

Tags: android, target

I read here: http://www.androidguys.com/2009/10/11/developers-can-now-target-by-carrier-in-android-market/ that it can be done if you go to the Android Market, and go to your app, then go to Publishing Options -> Locations, but I don't see anything to select a specific carrier there, only specific countries.

Is this something that Google changed? Can this still be done, or is it done automatically? Can't the carrier be detected from the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un-check "All Locations"

Then find the Country that you want to limit by carrier.  **Click on the country's name, it is a hyperlink.** This will then reveal the carriers for that country underneath it, such as US has

- All Carriers
- AT&T Mobility
- Sprint
- T-Mobile - US
- Verizon Wireless
- nTelos

**Example**:

[image]